# Material UI expand Select to fit label

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to automatically expand Material-UI's Select input to fit the size of the label?

The official demo adds minWidth to the formControl element, however I have a number of inputs and would like to avoid needing to set a series of hard coded sizes. When I remove this minWidth field the label gets squashed as in the below demo, the desired output is to have the label and required star fit neatly inside the Select element.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-x4m3x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `InputLabel`'s `min-width` to [`max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns#max-content).

Then on render, get the `InputLabel`'s `offsetWidth` and set that to `FormControl`'s `min-width`.

```js
export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState();
  const label = React.useRef();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(`${label.current.offsetWidth + 24}px`); // 24 for caret icon
  }, [label]);

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl
        required
        className={classes.formControl}
        style={{
          minWidth: labelWidth
        }}
      >
        <InputLabel
          id="demo-simple-select-required-label"
          style={{ minWidth: "max-content" }}
          ref={label}
        >
          The label
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className={classes.selectEmpty}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>An option</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

PS: You might already know, but I would still want to mention that `FormControl` accepts `fullWidth` prop that when set to `true`, it will take up the full width of its container.

Comment: Thanks for the response, just looking through it now. I need to better understand useRef as I've not used that yet. One concern is that so far I stuck to storing all state at a high level container and this would mean I need to add it to lower level components, otherwise I'm not sure how to scale this cleanly to dozens of Selects in different components.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do it with just CSS. `InputLabel`s are positioned `absolute`, and overriding its styles breaks the animations for me. `useRef` is pretty useful for selecting nodes, that's how I learned it actually :D you can check the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Comment: Thanks, I've been playing with it and I'm pretty happy with the solution. Unfortunately one issue I have is that when the select starts hidden by a parent div being hidden, it doesn't seem to calculate the correct width, even after the parent div is set to visible. If it matters I'm using <Grid item hidden={true/false}>. Any idea how to get the correct calculation in this case?

Comment: I guess we can't calculate the element's width if `display` is `none`. Do you have a codesandbox that I can check regarding your issue?

Comment: I'll make one. Give me a few mins.

Comment: Here's a quick example https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-m9xd0. In my real example I'm dynamically loading options based on a previous select.

Comment: Here's a [workaround](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ff9r1?file=/demo.js).

Comment: Sorry to be difficult but now it seems to have a problem whereby it doesn't fully disappear again elements to the right are pushed over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219799/discussion-between-bertdida-and-user).

Answer (score 0):

Heavily using bertdida's answer I eventually went with the below, and used in-place of Select. Changing the width of the select itself seems to work the best.

```
export default function SelectAutoWidth( props ) {
    const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState();
    const labelRef = React.createRef();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setLabelWidth(`${labelRef.current.offsetWidth + 24}px`); // 24 for caret icon
    }, [labelRef]);

    return (
        <FormControl
            required={props.required}>
            <InputLabel ref={labelRef}>{props.label}</InputLabel>
            <Select
                style={{
                    minWidth: labelWidth
                }}
                value={props.value}
                multiple={props.multiple}
                input={props.input}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                renderValue={props.renderValue}
            >
                {props.children}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    );
}
```